# 'RCTTextSelection.h' file not found error in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error after following [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@alentoma/react-native-selectable-text) in iOS. I have tried both manual installations in iOS and still I am getting this error.

Although it is working fine in Android and there is no build error. but as soon as I built it in iOS then it gives this error.

[image]